# Why is this loop not finding my files that are clearly there?

Tags: excel, vba

Everytime this script goes through to save `Wb`, it's saying that it can't find the file and asking if it's been deleted or placed elsewhere?

Files are in the correct folderpath that I designated, what could be causing this error?

I edited my code and this line is where the debugger stops:

```
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

Sub passwordprotect()

Dim fileName As Variant
Dim Wb As Workbook

folderpath = "C:\Realty Services Assessment\"
fileName = Dir(folderpath & "*.xlsx")

Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

While fileName <> ""


    Wb.SaveAs , password:="xxxxxxxxxxx"
    Wb.Close

    fileName = Dir
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: You're appending the `folderpath` twice.

Comment: I don't know VB, but what the asterisk means? Besides, `fileName` seems already included `folderpath`, I am not sure if the `folderpath & fileName` hurts.

Comment: You open `wb` outside of the loop before executing the loop (good!) and then... in your first iteration you close it... Your second iteration of the loop hits and `Wb` isn't open anymore to perform a `SaveAs`. Move that `Wb.Close` after the loop if you are wanting to `SaveAs` more than once.

Comment: Prepend the folder to the file name at the time you open it. So `Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(folderpath & fileName)`. You had that part right in the first version of the code, but you need to *move* that line *within* the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct loop is:

```
Sub passwordprotect()

Dim fileName As Variant
Dim Wb As Workbook

    folderpath = "C:\Realty Services Assessment\"
    fileName = Dir(folderpath & "*.xlsx")

    While fileName <> ""

        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(folderpath & fileName)
        Wb.SaveAs , password:="xxxxxxxxxxx"
        Wb.Close

        fileName = Dir
    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked, but it keeps giving me a `save as prompt`. I tried the `application.displayalerts = false` and a `savechanges:=True` but now it doesn't even password protect anymore

Comment: Sorry, I can't hep you there. I don't know how to suppress the prompt.